# How can I return a dictionary using a folder containing text files?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to return a dictionary that has the text file name as the key. I then have a dataframe that has three columns with different words. I want to return the count of every word from that column that shows up in the text file as the value. So for example I have  done `import os` and used the method `os.listdir()`  to display my list of text files.

```
myinput: 
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
txtlist = os.listdir("./data")
print(txtlist)

myoutput: 
['textone.txt', 'texttwo.txt', 'textthree.txt']
```

Next I have defined my dataframe of words I am looking for from an excel file.

```
myinput: 
wrdlist = pd.read_excel("words.xlsx")
wrdlist

myoutput: 
       Color       Shape       Description
0      red         square        happy
1      green       circle         sad
2     yellow      triangle        mad
3    navy blue      cube        disgust
```

I have used the dataframe to create a list that I can use for colors

```
myinput:
colorwrds = []
for word in wrdlist.Color:
     colorwrds.append(re.compile(r"\b"+word+r"\b"))
```

Finally I want to use all of these to return the dictionary that has the file as a key and the count of colors as the value. So file textone.txt has the words navy blue once and red twice, texttwo.txt has yellow twice, green once, navy blue once and red once, and textthree.txt has red once.

```
Desiredoutput:
{'textone.txt' : 3, 'texttwo.txt' : 5, 'textthree.txt':1}
```

I was trying to create a function like this but I am not sure if I am doing it right.

```
attemptedinput to achieve desired output:

def counterfunction(textfilelist, importantwordslist):
     mydict = {}
     for wordname in importantwordslist.lower():
          mydict[wordname] = 0
     for wordname in textfilelist.lower():
          if wordname in mydict.keys():
               mydict[wordname] += 1
     return mydict

print(counterfunction(txtlist, wrdlist)
```

Comment: Please always provide sample input / output! [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the wordcount from a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': {0: 'red', 1: 'green', 2: 'yellow', 3: 'navy_blue'},
 'Shape': {0: 'square', 1: 'circle', 2: 'triangle', 3: 'cube'},
 'Description': {0: 'happy', 1: 'sad', 2: 'mad', 3: 'disgust'}})

colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']


color_count = sum([n for c, n in Counter(df.to_numpy().flatten()).items() if c in colors])

print(color_count)
#3
```

So without having any sample data, it might look like this:

```
import os
root = r'D:\Test'
filenames = [r'textone.txt', r'texttwo.txt', r'textthree.txt']
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']

dict_results = dict()
for file in filenames:
    path = os.path.join(root, filenames)
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    color_count = sum([n for c, n in Counter(df.to_numpy().flatten()).items() if c in colors])
    dict_results[file] = color_count = sum([n for c, n in Counter(df.to_numpy().flatten()).items() if c in colors])
```